# Custom Post Type Archive Links Not Working

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, custom-post-type-archives

I have multiple custom post types set up. I've been through this process many times, on many sites and have never once had a problem with it.

The post type is registered as 'glossary'.
The archive is 'archive-glossary.php'.
The single is 'single-glossary.php'.

On my archive page, I basically have the following:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

etc...

If you click one of those links that would normally take you to a single-glossary.php it just reloads archive-glossary.php.

I have many post types set up the exact same way, on the same site. I'm just beginning to work out a page template, so they're all very generic. I've flushed the permalinks, deleted and re-registered the post type, changed the theme, checked and double-checked for typos, cleared my browser cache totally, used 4 different browsers, and just can't see anything that would be causing this.

I'm hoping someone can offer some sage troubleshooting advice.

Upon request, the following is what I use to create custom post types:

```
class CustomPostType{
    protected $textdomain;
    protected $posts;

    public function __construct($textdomain){
        $this->textdomain = $textdomain;
        $this->posts = array();
        add_action('init', array(&$this, 'register_custom_post'));
    }

    public function make($type, $properLabel, $singularLabel, $pluralLabel, $icon, $slug, $settings = array()){
        if(isset($singularLabel)){$singluarLabel = $singularLabel;}else{$singularLabel = '';}
        if(isset($pluralLabel)){$pluralLabel = $pluralLabel;}else{$pluralLabel = '';}
        $default_settings = array(
            'labels' => array(
                //Title Of the Group
                'name' => __($properLabel, $this->textdomain),
                //Individual Type
                'singular_name' => __($singluarLabel, $this->textdomain),
                // "All %Items%" Menu Item
                'all_items' => __( 'All '.$pluralLabel, $this->textdomain), 
                //The "Add New" Menu Item
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New '.$singularLabel, $this->textdomain ),
                //Add New Display Title 
                'add_new_item' => __('Add New '.$singularLabel, $this->textdomain), 
                //Edit Dialog
                'edit' => __( 'Edit', $this->textdomain), /* Edit Dialog */
                //Edit Display Title
                'edit_item' => __('Edit '.$pluralLabel, $this->textdomain),
                //New Display Title
                'new_item' => __('New '.$singularLabel, $this->textdomain),
                //View Display Title
                'view_item' => __('View '.$singularLabel, $this->textdomain),
                //Search Custom Type Title
                'search_items' => __('Search '.$pluralLabel, $this->textdomain),
                //Displays if No Entry Found
                'not_found' => __('No '.$pluralLabel.' found.', $this->textdomain),
                //Not found in Trash
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('No '.$pluralLabel.' found in trash.', $this->textdomain),
                //Only in Hierarchical Post Types "Parent %Item%"
                'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent '.$singluarLabel, $this->textdomain),
                ),
            //Custom Type Description
            'description' => __( 'This is the '.$properLabel.' custom post type', $this->textdomain), /* Custom Type Description */
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_position' => 20,
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/library/images/admin-panel/'.$icon.'-icon.png',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => $slug
                ),
            'has_archive' => sanitize_title_with_dashes($slug),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports' => array(
                'title',
                'editor',
                'author',
                'thumbnail',
                'excerpt',
                'custom-fields',
                'revisions',
                'sticky',
                'page-attributes'
                ),
            );
        $this->posts[$type] = array_merge($default_settings, $settings);
    }

    public function register_custom_post(){
        foreach($this->posts as $key=>$value) {
            register_post_type($key, $value);
        }
    }
}//End Class

$type_glossary = new CustomPostType('thetextdomain');
$type_glossary->make('glossary', 'Glossary', 'Term', 'Terms', 'glossary', 'glossary');
```

Comment: Post you code that you use to register your post type

Comment: Edited to add code used to register post type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try registering with a different name; doesn't always make sense, but it's a proper check.

if that doesn't resolve – which would be strange since the other CPTs work – check any functions/plugins hooking into template_redirect. might even need to do a backtrace to see the file load progression. not sure if it does this specifically, but [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) is a fantastic plugin for devving and solving issues.

Comment: Thank you. It was a redirect left over from the last theme I did, and I completely forgot that it was buried there.

Thank you doubly for mentioning Query Monitor, which I have somehow never come across but offers an amazing wealth of information!